# WPF не работает Binding на FontSize внутри DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

Здравствуйте!
Программа написанна на WPF MVVM с использованием фреймворка caliburn Micro.
Возникла необходимость динамически менять размер шрифта элемента в ListView.

Данная привязка на FontSize не отрабатывает

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="dgffsdgf" FontSize="{Binding Path= FontSizeTb8X2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

а такая работает нормально:

```
<TextBlock Name="CurrentFontString" Margin="10" MinHeight="20" FontSize="{Binding Path= FontSizeTb8X2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

и такая тоже

```
<Style x:Key="ListHeaderStyle8X2" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Path= FontSizeTb8X2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Style>
```

КОД **View**

```
<Style x:Key="ListHeaderStyle8X2" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Path= FontSizeTb8X2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Style>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Name="FontChoser" Content="ШРИФТ"/>
    <TextBlock Name="CurrentFontString"/>

    <ListView Name="TestListViewFonts">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListHeaderStyle8X2}">
                <GridViewColumn  Header="Номер">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="dgffsdgf" FontSize="{Binding Path= FontSizeTb8X2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

КОД **ViewModel**

```
private float _fontSizeTb8X2;
public float FontSizeTb8X2
{
    get { return _fontSizeTb8X2; }
    set
    {
        _fontSizeTb8X2 = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FontSizeTb8X2);
    }
}


//Окно настройки шрифта из WinForms
public void FontChoser()
{
    var fontDialog = new FontDialog { Font = CurrentFont };
    if (fontDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {   
        FontSizeTb8X2 = fontDialog.Font.Size;
        CurrentFontString= $@"{FontSizeTb8X2}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Привязка не срабатывает, т.к. `ListView` (как и любой `ItemsControl`) устанавливает контекст своим дочерним элементам на сами элементы привязанной коллекции. Свойства `FontSizeTb8X2` в этом контексте, естественно, нет. Поэтому вам нужно использовать `RelativeSource` для указания точного пути к этому свойству, например:

```
FontSize="{Binding Path=DataContext.FontSizeTb8X2,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

или чуть-чуть короче:

```
FontSize="{Binding DataContext.FontSizeTb8X2,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: Точно! Спасибо за объяснение. Т.е. DataContext, это контекст всего окна (Window), поэтому указывая источник на Window, мы имеем доступ к свойствам ViewModel?

Comment: Да, именно к свойствам той VM, что является контекстом Window