# Привязка из контекстного меню

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть DataGrid в которой в DataGridRowDetail нужно сделать binding context menu к главной view model. Как это сделать? Оно сейчас пишет что не может найти property непосредственно в ObservableCollection DataGridRows а мне нужно чтоб оно искало не в коллекции а в view model где коллекция

> Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.OpenEditWindowCommand; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem>
    <DataGrid>
      <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
              <ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu.Items>
                  <MenuItem Command="{Binding 
                    DataContext.OpenEditWindowCommand,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                    AncestorType=Window},
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                 </MenuItem>
               </ContextMenu.Items>
             </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
          </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Добавьте код, иллюстрирующий проблему

Comment: Через `FindAncestor`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/724594/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP не находит

Comment: @АндрейNOP добавил в сообщение

Comment: Покажите разметку (желательно выбросив всё неотносящееся к делу)

Comment: @АндрейNOP добавил

Comment: Ааа, ну конечно, у вас там `ContextMenu` :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, и я не могу сделать binding главной view model..

Comment: `ContextMenu` это важная деталь, смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что контекстное меню лежит отдельно от визуального дерева окна, поэтому `FindAncestor` не сработает — он ищет только вверх по дереву. Не сработает здесь и фича `ElementName`, потому что она ищет тоже только внутри дерева (хоть и не только вверх).

Что вам поможет — это фича `x:Reference` (доступно с .NET 4.0), она ищет по всему XAML. Присвойте в разметке окну имя, например `<Window ... Name="w">` и укажите его как источник:

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenEditWindowCommand,
                            Source={x:Reference w},
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Comment: а если все это дело лежит в словаре ресурсов? как в таком случае поступить?

Comment: Задайте отдельным вопросом, подумаем, возможно придется писать свое расширение разметки