# Не работает привязка свойства IsChecked ContextMenu к свойству свойству Visibility DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо привязать свойство IsChecked ContextMenu к свойству Visibility DataGridTextColumn.

**ContextMenu**

```
<Control.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ColumnHeaderMenu">
            <MenuItem x:Name="MI_IdInstruction" Header="Id_Instruction" IsCheckable="true" IsChecked="True"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ResourceDictionary> 
</Control.Resources>
```

**DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Instructions}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderMenu}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding IdSI}"
                    Header="IdSI_Header"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility ="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource converterVisibility}, ElementName=MI_IdInstruction , Mode=TwoWay}"/> 
 </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

**Converter**

```
class ConverterVisibility : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Я понял что проблемам в том что Контекстное меню из за того что находиться в ресурсах не входит в дерево построения.
Как лучше сделать такую привязку?

Comment: А если попробовать через `x:Reference`, как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/866493/218063 ?

Comment: Но вообще, мне кажется, лучше вынести это в отдельное свойство в vm, т. к. контекстное меню может и не отображаться