# WPF Объединение ContextMenu разных контролов

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть два любых контрола. Один главный, второй дочерний. У каждого есть свой `ContextMenu`. Нужно, чтобы вызвав `ContextMenu` у дочернего там был `MenuItem` и главного. Объединение я сделал, но команды не работают. Как правильно объединить `ContextMenu` и чтобы работали команды?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
MainWindow:

```
 <Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainMenuViewModel></local:MainMenuViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel Width="100" Height="150" Background="Red">
    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Main Context Menu" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
    <Button Width="100" Height="100" Content="Button" Background="Red">
        <local:InheritMenu.ParentMenu>
            <Binding Path="ContextMenu" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}" />
        </local:InheritMenu.ParentMenu>
        <local:InheritMenu.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Button Context" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </local:InheritMenu.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

ViewModel

```
class MainMenuViewModel
{
    private RelayCommand testCommand;
    public ICommand TestCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (testCommand == null)
            {
                testCommand = new RelayCommand(
                                        x =>
                                        {
                                            MessageBox.Show("TestCommand");
                                        },

                                        y => true);
            }

            return testCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

InheritMenu

```
public static class InheritMenu
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContextMenuProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ContextMenu", typeof(ContextMenu), typeof(InheritMenu), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnContextMenuChanged));
    private static void OnContextMenuChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetContextMenu(d as FrameworkElement);
    }
    public static void SetContextMenu(FrameworkElement element, ContextMenu value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ContextMenuProperty, value);
    }
    public static ContextMenu GetContextMenu(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        return (ContextMenu)element.GetValue(ContextMenuProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentMenuProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ParentMenu", typeof(ContextMenu), typeof(InheritMenu), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnParentMenuChanged));
    private static void OnParentMenuChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetContextMenu(d as FrameworkElement);
    }
    public static void SetParentMenu(FrameworkElement element, ContextMenu value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ParentMenuProperty, value);
    }
    public static ContextMenu GetParentMenu(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        return (ContextMenu)element.GetValue(ParentMenuProperty);
    }

    private static void SetContextMenu(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        var context = GetContextMenu(element);
        var parent = GetParentMenu(element);

        if (context == null || parent == null) return;

        var menu = new ContextMenu();

        foreach (var item in parent.Items)
        {
            menu.Items.Add(SimpleXamlClone(item));
        }

        menu.Items.Add(new Separator());

        foreach (var item in context.Items)
        {
            menu.Items.Add(SimpleXamlClone(item));
        }

        element.ContextMenu = menu;
    }

    public static object SimpleXamlClone(object original)
    {
        var xaml = XamlWriter.Save(original);
        var reader = new StringReader(xaml);
        var xml = XmlReader.Create(reader);
        return XamlReader.Load(xml);
    }
}
```

RelayCommand

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/866493/204383