# Не работает кнопка в элементе списка

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В общем, есть такой список

```
<ListBox  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Grid>
              <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}"/>
              </StackPanel>
              <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedVM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
              <Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
              </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Как видите, в шаблоне элементов списка есть кнопка и чекбокс. Проблема только в том, что они не работают вообще. При нажатии на кнопку происходит стандартная анимация нажатия и на этом все, ничего не происходит. Чекбокс привязан к свойству `IsCheckedVM`, которое по умолчанию равно `false`, и когда нажимаешь на кнопку, то происходит определенная команда, которая за одно передает свойству `IsCheckedVM` состояние `true` и чекбокс должен быть `checked`. Но ничего не происходит и я не знаю почему. Даже если в конструкторе VM задать свойству `IsCheckedVM = true`, то чекбокс элемента все равно будет `не checked`. Т.е. чтобы я не делал, но я почему-то не могу воздействовать ни на кнопку, ни на чекбокс в элементе, что делать? Сами по себе эти кнопка с чекбоксом работают отлично, такая проблема возникает только если их запихнуть в шаблон, но мне это необходимо.

Comment: `Сами по себе эти кнопка с чекбоксом работают отлично` - это если за пределами `ListBox`? `такая проблема возникает только если их запихнуть в шаблон` - внутрь `ListBoxItem`? Если да, то в первом варианте у вас используется VM главная (назовем ее `MainViewModel`), а во втором случае у вас используется VM объекта, который вы указали в привязанной коллекции (прим: `public List<ItemViewModel> { get; }`). То есть ваша команда `SomeCommand` и все другие свойства должны быть внутри `ItemViewModel`. Если я "копаю" не в ту сторону, то предоставьте самодостаточный пример, что бы я мог проверить у себя.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, именно так. То есть чтобы чекбокс с кнопкой работали, мне нужно прописать команду не в MainViewModel, а в VM объекта?

Comment: Как один из вариантов, да. Либо привязывать к главной vm, либо вовсе пробрасывать главную vm в нужную vm через тот же конструктор.  Но свою ошибку я думаю вы поняли.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ все равно не получается, даже если в шаблоне у кнопки с чекбоксом напрямую задать DataContext, как например вот так
`<CheckBox.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainVM/>
</CheckBox.DataContext>`

То как бы так сказать, работает влияние на саму MainVM, т.е. например командой какое-то свойство меняется, но на саму VIEW это не влияет. По команде должно происходить определенное действие во View, но не происходит. И кстати вне шаблона если задать таким же  образом  кнопке с чекбоксом DataContext, они таким же образом начинают себя вести (т.е. также плохо)

Comment: Оставлю [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553) здесь. Ну а по вопросу, я вам сказал, что у вас 3 пути: **1.** Создать все свойства в VM нужного объекта (который задан в привязанной коллекции). **2.** Передать ссылку на главную VM внутрь VM объекта через конструктор и сделать там публичное свойство главной VM через которое и привязываетесь. **3.** Привязаться через XAML к дочернему объекту с помощью [FindAncestor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/724594/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ О, спасибо большое, третий вариант помог