# Как забиндить checkbox к свойствам, которые не в ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, как забиндить CheckBox к свойству, которое находится в том же классе, что и Card. Проблема в том, что когда я указываю IsChecked="{Binding ...}", то у меня указываются свойства Card, а мне нужны свойства класса, в котором находится Card. Буду очень благодарен за помощь

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridReestr" ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}" FontSize="14" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn IsReadOnly="False" CanUserReorder="False" Binding="{Binding IsSelectedCard, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding }"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/724594/220553

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Не представляете как сильно помогли