# События Controls.Label

Tags: c#, maui

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label - если ничего не упустил, нет никакого события связанного с кликом. Как в таком случае можно поступить ? Мне нужно при клике на него, получить текст.

Он является дочерным объектом CollectionView

Но получение всего объекта мне не нужно, так как я хотел бы каждое свойства элемента получать по отдельности.

Comment: Лейбл - это же не кнопка, зачем по нему кликать? А вообще странно, что в нем нет события, я думал у всех уи элементов оно есть

Comment: @tym32167 - да - согласен что не кнопка, но я в него вывожу текст и хотелось бы при клике получать содержимое. Получается что нужно использовать кнопку для этого) ?

Comment: кнопку или гиперссылку - что то, что интуитивно можно кликнуть

Comment: В проектах, где используется XAML (А MAUI один из таких), люди стараются отделять UI от кода, для этого используют не события, а команды. Если вы хотите сделать кликабельным некий объект, то у вас несколько вариантов: 1. Использовать `Button`, которому вы уберете фон, обводку, и все лишнее, и им уже обернете этот контрол. 2. Использовать так называемые "поведения" (Behaviors), например [EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior).

Comment: Ну а так... [Создание гиперссылки](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/label#create-a-hyperlink)

Comment: Можно наверное на лейбл навесить Flyout, а в него кнопку положить, а может и не можно, я не проверял. А вообще верно пишут, надо с данными работать а не с контролами.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, пробую гиперссылку, но не могу никак подобраться к `Command` в `VM`, так как гиперссылка внутри `CollectionView` и получается достаться только свойста `M`, пробовал использовать `RelativeSource` - но всё равно не удалось. С наскока не удалось, ушёл изучать привязки.

Comment: Как вы наверно знаете, свойства для привязки ищутся в `DataContext` (не знаю как в MAUI зовется свойство), когда вы пишете условно `<ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Items}">...</ListBox>`, и пытаетесь внутри переопределить например шаблон, то все, что внутри, будет иметь `DataContext` к конкретному элементу привязанной коллекции, а не к классу, в котором лежит эта коллекция. Чтоб достать основной класс, вам надо перейти на слой выше, можно это сделать например [через предка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/724594/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - всё - понял, спасибо!