# Привязка команды к кнопке, находящийся в элементе ListBox MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня есть ListBox и в каждом элементе кнопка. Как я могу привязать команду к этой кнопке и узнать в каком элементе была нажата кнопка. Использую MVVM.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
                mc:Ignorable="d"
                xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:AAAcasino.ViewModels.ClientViewModels.AdminViewModels">

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CreationQuizViewModel}">
    <Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:CreationQuizViewModel}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding QuizModel.Name}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Quest}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <StackPanel  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddQuizNodeCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveQuizCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding QuizModel.QuizNodes}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Question}"/>
                            <TextBox Text=""/>
                            <Button Content="Add answer" Command=""/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                        <Expander Header="Ответы" Grid.Row="1">
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Str}"/>
                                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsCorrect}"/>
                                        </WrapPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </Expander>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

```
 internal class CreationQuizViewModel : ViewModel, IPageViewModel
 {
     #region IPage
     public string Title => "Создание викторины";
     public MainWindowViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }
     public void SetAnyModel(object? model)
     {
         QuizModel = (QuizModel)model;
     }
 #endregion
     private QuizModel? _quizModel = new QuizModel();
 public QuizModel? QuizModel
 {
     get => _quizModel;
     set => Set(ref _quizModel, value);
 }
 private string? _quest;
 public string Quest
 {
     get => _quest;
     set => Set(ref _quest, value);
 }
 #region command
 public ICommand AddQuizNodeCommand { get; set; }
 private void OnAddQuizNodeCommand(object param)
 {
     QuizNode node = new QuizNode();
     node.Question = Quest;
     QuizModel.AddQuizNode(node);
 }
 private bool CanAddQuizNodeCommand(object param) => true;
 public ICommand SaveQuizCommand { get; set; }
 private void OnSaveQuizCommand(object param)
 {
     Task.Run(() =>
     {
         int existance = (from q in MainWindowViewModel.applicationContext.quizModels.ToList()
                          where q == QuizModel
                          select q).Count();
         if (existance > 0)
             MainWindowViewModel.applicationContext.Update(QuizModel);
         else
             MainWindowViewModel.applicationContext.Add(QuizModel);

         MainWindowViewModel.applicationContext.SaveChanges();
     });
     MainViewModel.SelectedPageViewModel = MainViewModel.ClientPageViewModels[(int)NumberClientPage.ADMIN_PAGE];
 }
 private bool CanSaveQuizCommand(object parameter) => (QuizModel.Name != "" && QuizModel.Name != null);
 #endregion
 public CreationQuizViewModel()
 {
     AddQuizNodeCommand = new LamdaCommand(OnAddQuizNodeCommand, CanAddQuizNodeCommand);
     SaveQuizCommand = new LamdaCommand(OnSaveQuizCommand, CanSaveQuizCommand);
 }
```

}

```
internal class QuizModel :ViewModel
{
private int _id;
public int ID
{
    get => _id;
    set => _id = value;
}

private string? _name = null;
public string? Name
{
    get => _name;
    set => Set(ref _name, value);
}

private ObservableCollection<QuizNode> _quizNodes = new ObservableCollection<QuizNode>();
public ObservableCollection<QuizNode> QuizNodes { get => _quizNodes; }
public void AddQuizNode(QuizNode node) { _quizNodes.Add(node); }
public void RemoveQuizNode(QuizNode node) { _quizNodes.Remove(node); }
}

internal class Answer : ViewModel
{
private int _id;
public int ID
{
    get => _id;
    set => _id = value;
}
private string _str;
public string Str
{
    get => _str;
    set => Set(ref _str, value);
}

private bool _correctness = false;
public bool IsCorrect
{
    get => _correctness;
    set => Set(ref _correctness, value);
}

}
```

В QuizNode коллекция Answer и string Question

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/724594/220553

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Теперь команду видно в разметке, но ее вызов не происходит.            <Button Content="Add answer" Margin="10 0 0 0"
        Command="{Binding AddAnswerCommand, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=vm:CreationQuizViewModel}}"/>

Comment: А при чем тут vm? Не придумывайте своего, внимательно посмотрите на ответ. Вот откройте XAML и посмотрите, как там располагаются элементы, поймете, что они располагаются в неком древовидном порядке, где некоторые находятся друг в друге, а некоторые содержат своих потомков. Вот у вас все, что внутри `ItemTemplate` - это потомки, которые имеют свои данные, вам нужны данные родителя, а значит и найти надо родителя. То есть, у вас должно быть `Binding DataContext.AddAnswerCommand` (ибо у родителя наша VM это `DataContext`), `AncestorType=ListBox` (ибо он родитель всех внутренних объектов).

Comment: Спасибо за исправление.